# Service "ERROR: Unable to load type" for a remote Master

Tags: ros, remote-roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My setup is an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM on Win10, and RaspberryPi running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS. I have ROS Kinetic installed on both of the Ubuntu machines and they can ping each other with hostname fine.
I wrote a new node on my remote Master (which is the RPi) that exposes 2 services and I can call the services fine locally on the RPi. The node is reachable from the Ubuntu VM, I can `rosnode ping` and can see it in `rosservice list`. However, when I `rosservice info` it from the VM, I get:

```
$ rosservice info get_humid_rh  
Node: /sht15_node  
URI: rosrpc://mlotfy-pi:36003  
Type: sht15/GetHumidRh  
ERROR: Unable to load type [sht15/GetHumidRh].  
Have you typed 'make' in [sht15]?
```

When I try to `rosservice call` it from the VM, I get:

```
$ rosservice call get_humid_rh  
ERROR: Unable to load type [sht15/GetHumidRh].  
Have you typed 'make' in [sht15]?
```

What could be missing here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254699/service-%22error:-unable-to-load-type%22-for-a-remote-master/) by [mlotfy](https://answers.ros.org/users/29366/mlotfy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Message definitions will need to be present on *all* hosts that want to participate in the ROS node graph.

In other words: make sure the workspace in your VM has a copy of the message package and build the workspace.

PS: this is one of the reasons why having packages with *just* messages is a good idea: that way you can access remote services / topics without needing to have the rest of the software duplicated as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mlotfy](https://answers.ros.org/users/29366/mlotfy/) on 2017-02-15**:
You made my day! That worked. Thanks for the design advice as well, it will take me sometime to learn ROS design patterns.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-15**:
Start [here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ros_best_practices/wiki).